# Usando SendMessage com aplicativos como Notepad, Word, DreamWeaver

Tags: c#

Estou tendo dificuldade em trabalhar com o `SendMessage()`, em alguns programas funciona de um método e com outros de outro...

Para escrever no Notepad, faço o seguinte:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr Handle, uint Message, int lparam, int wParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx") ]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr Child, string lparam, string wParam);

static Process p = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad")[0];
public static void Message()
{
    string msg = "Teste";
    IntPtr child = DLLs.FindWindowEx(p.MainWindowHandle, new IntPtr(0), "Edit", null);
    foreach(char c in msg){
        DLLs.PostMessage(child, 0x102, Convert.ToChar(c), 0);
    }
}
```

Porém seu eu precisar enviar uma mensagem para um jogo, uma planilha em Word, Notepad++, DreamWeaver, etc, não funciona...

Como funciona em outros casos? Li um pouco sobre Spy++, mas seria só assim mesmo?

Answer (score 3):

A API do Windows é muito poderosa, e é divertido experimentar as coisas que podemos fazer com ela.

No entanto, você está literalmente hackeando esses programas, se você quer escrever em suas janelas (ou clicar em seus botões internos, ativar funcionalidades como salvar etc.) dessa forma. Existe uma chance muito alta do seu código ter a execução bloqueada, pelo próprio Windows ou por um antivírus.

Mas não se desanime, existem outras formas de se comunicar com vários desses programas. Muitas vezes os desenvolvedores deles permitem que outros programas de terceiros interajam com eles. É o caso de todos os programas do Office (Word, Excel, Power Point etc.). Esses programas têm API's próprias, que são mais simples e melhor documentadas do que as API's do Windows.

No caso do Office, as API's oficiais se chamam *Office Primary Interop Assemblies* e *Visual Studio Tools for Office*. Melhor do que usar essas ferramentas, no entanto, é usar o [NetOffice](https://osdn.net/projects/netoffice/), uma camada wrapper que facilita muito as coisas.

No caso do Dreamweaver, você usa as [API's de extensão](https://www.adobe.com/support/dreamweaver/extend.html). Nesse caso você vai trabalhar com Javascript, não com C#.

Para o Notepad++, você pode [fazer seus próprios plugins](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/contribute/plugin-howto.html). A página linkada aqui é um tutorial para fazer seu primeiro plugin em 10 minutos ;) Dê uma olhada no final da página, tem um exemplo de plugin feito em C#.

Outros programas podem ou não ter API's que você possa usar. Fica a seu critério pesquisar por cada um. Em geral, os software mais utilizados no mundo costumam ter alguma forma de integração via API. Boa sorte e bom aprendizado!

Comment: Obrigado, vou dar uma lida!